divergence theorem auf gauss on disc
Suppose we have
a regular surface $ B = \{x^2 + y^2 < or = 5, z=0 \}, S = \{x^2+y^2 < or = 1, z=0 \}$, so $S \subset B$ ( $S$ and $B$ are on $x-y$-plane) and a vector field $X(x,y,0)=(x^2,y,0)$. We define $X$ as a vector field on $B$, so $X:B\rightarrow TpB$ for all $p \in B$.
Now Gauss theorem says $\int_{S}\text{div }(X)dA = \int_{\partial S}\langle X,v\rangle ds$ with v = unit normalfield on $\partial S$. Here $v = (x,y,0)$ for $(x,y,0) \in \partial S$. If I compute both integrals I get different values:$\\$
$\int_{\partial S}\langle X,v\rangle ds = \int_{\partial S} x^3+y^2 ds = \int_{0}^{2\pi}\cos^3(z)+\sin^2(z) dz = \pi$ and $\int_{S}\text{div }(X)dA = \int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{1}2r \cos(z)+1 drdz = 2\pi$ . ($S$ parametrized with $(r \cos z,r\sin z,0)$). Why do I get different values? The requirements of the theorem are fulfilled: X is smooth and differentiable on B and $\text{supp }(X) = B$ so its compact.

First, using $z$ as a letter here is highly confusing and inappropriate, since it is already a known quantity. Use something innocent like $\theta$ or $t$. Anyhow, recall that in polar coordinates $dA = r,dr,d\theta$. Also, please do not use irrelevant tags. I have removed three of your four.

Thanks for the answer, I will regard your feedback for my next posts.
